# How can I get the original attribute of a Field object in java?

Tags: java, resources, field

I am iterating through the Fields of a class and I need to return the original class of it's Field.

The class I'm iterating is full of "Resource" objects which I'm iterating. And I need to return the "Resource" object instead the "Field" object. How can I do it?

```
 private Resource getPredicate(String header) {
    for(Field field : VCARD4.class.getDeclaredFields()){
        String name = field.getName();
        if(header.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){

        }
    }
```

Comment: [`Field.getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaringClass--)?

Comment: @AndyTurner this is for getting the declared class, and I want the class of the Field in question. I don't see a way of doing it

Comment: What do you mean by the *class* of the Field. Do you mean the type? In that case, `getType()`.

Comment: When I try to cast it with .getType() I get: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource (java.lang.Class is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: That's because it returns a `Class`, not a `Resource`. Do you mean you want the *value* of the field?

Comment: Yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Search for the word "value" in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

class VCARD4 {
    Resource resource_a = new FileSystemResource("/dev/null");
    Resource resource_b = new FileSystemResource("/dev/null");
    Class<?> class_a = Object.class;

    public Resource getResource_a() {
        return resource_a;
    }

    public Resource getResource_b() {
        return resource_b;
    }

    public Class<?> getClass_a() {
        return class_a;
    }
}

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VCARD4 vcard4 = new VCARD4();

        Object fieldValue = getPredicate(vcard4, "resource_a");

        System.out.println("Field value: " + fieldValue);
        System.out.println("Field class name: " + fieldValue.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Field superclass name: " + fieldValue.getClass().getGenericSuperclass().getTypeName());
    }

    private static Object getPredicate(VCARD4 object, String fieldName) {
        AtomicReference<Object> targetField = new AtomicReference<>();

        Arrays.stream(PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(VCARD4.class))
                .filter(property -> property.getReadMethod().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("get" + fieldName))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(foundField -> {
                    Method method = foundField.getReadMethod();
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    targetField.set(ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, object));
                });

        return targetField.get();
    }
}
```

That would give you basically a value of a class VCARD4 specified field.
Hope this helps.